# Getting a list of classes and collections that have second level caching enabled

Tags: nhibernate, second-level-cache

Given a reference to an `ISessionFactory` instance, is it possible to get a list of all classes and collections which have second level caching enabled for them?

**Edit:**

To give a little more context for what I'm trying to achieve:

I'd like to build an administration interface that can provide the ability to flush portions of the second level cache using `sessionFactory.Evict` and `sessionFactory.EvictCollection`. More information can be found [here](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#performance-sessioncache).

For example:

- Flush all entities of this type
- Flush this specific entity
- Flush all collections of this entity
- Flush this specific collection of entities

For this, I will need a way to dynamically list the entity and entity collection types that are available for performing flush operations on.

Comment: Can you also get a reference to the `Configuration` object which was used to create the `ISessionFactory`? Or you only have the `ISessionFactory` and you cannot access the `Configuration`?

Comment: My ideal scenario would be to use an ISessionFactory instance..but if that's not possible, I could probably work something out with a Configuration object.

Comment: It can be also done with the ISessionFactory, see my answer below. Because you haven't mentioned which kind of information you need from the cached entites/collection I've only provided some sample code what you start to work with. If you have some more spefic needs just include them in question and I will try to also extend my answer.

Comment: @nemesv - see my edits above for further context.

Comment: I've extended my answer with some code to collect the cached entity type names and the cached collection roles what you can you use for the Evict and EvictCollection. Other than that you can explore the API of the metadata and the persister with the help of the debugger and I'm sure that you can find any other information what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `GetAllClassMetadata()` and the  `GetAllCollectionMetadata()` methods the get the metadata from the persistent clasess and the collections.

The trick is that you need to cast the returned metadata classes to `IEntityPersister` and `ICollectionPersister` where you can now check for the `Cache` property which should not be `null` if caching is configured for the entity/collection.

So your could will look like this

```
var cachedEnityTypes = new List<string>();
var cachedCollectionRoles = new List<string>();
foreach (var classMetadata in sessionFactory.GetAllClassMetadata())
{
    var persister = classMetadata.Value as IEntityPersister;
    if (persister != null && persister.Cache != null)
        cachedEnityTypes.Add(persister.EntityName);
}
foreach (var collectionMetadata in nHibernateSessionFactory.GetAllCollectionMetadata())
{
    var persister = collectionMetadata.Value as ICollectionPersister;
    if (persister != null && persister.Cache != null)
        cachedCollectionRoles.Add(collectionMetadata.Value.Role);
}
```